# ChainMapper is not able to resolve type

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to add multiple Mapper in a single program.

Here is two Mapper in class class and ChainMapper for the same. But when am adding Mapper in addMapper getting error.

> The method `addMapper(JobConf, Class<? extends Mapper<K1,V1,K2,V2>>, Class<? extends K1>, Class<? extends V1>, Class<? extends K2>, Class<? extends V2>, boolean, JobConf)` in the type ChainMapper is not applicable for the arguments `(Job, Class<Multiplication.CooccurrenceMapper>, Class<LongWritable>, Class<Text>, Class<Text>, Class<Text>, Configuration))`

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.ChainMapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.MultipleInputs;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Multiplication {
    public static class CooccurrenceMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

        // MAP METHOD
        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            //input: movie_2 \t movie_1=relation
            //pass data to reducer

            String[] line = value.toString().split("\t");
            context.write(new Text(line[0]), new Text(line[1]));
        }
    }

    public static class RatingMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

        // MAP METHOD
        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            //input: user,movie,rating
            //pass data to reducer
            String[] line = value.toString().split(",");
            context.write(new Text(line[1]), new Text(line[0] + ':' + line[2]));

        }
    }

    public static class MultiplicationReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> {
        // REDUCE METHOD
        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            //key = movie_2 value = <movie_1=relation, movie_3=relation... userA:rating, userB:rating...>
            //collect the data for each movie, then do the multiplication
            Map<String, Double> relationMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
            Map<String, Double> ratingMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();

            for (Text value:values){
                if (values.toString().contains("=")){
                    String[] movie_relation = value.toString().split("=");
                    relationMap.put(movie_relation[0], Double.parseDouble(movie_relation[1]));
                }
                else{
                    String[] user_rating = value.toString().split(":");
                    ratingMap.put(user_rating[0], Double.parseDouble(user_rating[1]));
                }
            }

            for(Map.Entry<String, Double> entry: relationMap.entrySet()){
                String movie = entry.getKey();
                double relation = entry.getValue();

                for (Map.Entry<String, Double> element: ratingMap.entrySet()){
                    String user = element.getKey();
                    double rating = element.getValue();
                    context.write(new Text(user + ':' + movie), new DoubleWritable(relation*rating));
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(Multiplication.class);

        ChainMapper.addMapper(job, CooccurrenceMapper.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class, Text.class, Text.class, conf);  //Error
        ChainMapper.addMapper(job, RatingMapper.class, Text.class, Text.class, Text.class, Text.class, conf); /Error

        job.setMapperClass(CooccurrenceMapper.class);
        job.setMapperClass(RatingMapper.class);

        job.setReducerClass(MultiplicationReducer.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]), TextInputFormat.class, CooccurrenceMapper.class);
        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]), TextInputFormat.class, RatingMapper.class);

        TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

Why error is comming in ChainMapper.addMapper line in main method ?

Answer (score 0):

The first mapper takes inputs of `<Long, Text>` and produces outputs of `<Text, Text>`.  The second one does the same.  So the output key of the first one is `Long` while the input of the second is `Text`